# Is there a way to start a scrpy crwal with clean jobdir?

Tags: python-2.7, scrapy

After a paused crawl I want to restart the crawl with a JOBDIR option enabled to persist the state of the new crawl, but I do want to erase the state of the previous crawl as the data is obsolete.

There is no start/stop/resume for scrapy, the only command to manage the crawl is

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your intention is to start a *new* crawl, as opposed to resuming a *previously paused* crawl, you have to either delete the old directory, or specify a new directory:

```
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-2
scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-3
...
```

Starting and resuming happens with the same command, but based on the directory name. So if you specify a new directory it is considered a "start". If you specify an existing directory it is considered a "resume".
You can stop/pause a crawl by pressing `Ctrl+C`. Refer to the documentation: https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/jobs.html#how-to-use-it

Comment: Yes, I expect some flags. New dir for each similar case is not convenient, one may end up having dozens of dirs, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, but it is trivial to clean them. You could have a scheduled task on your system to remove old directories. You could even delete the directory as part of the same command, for example on Linux:
`rm -rf crawls/somespider-1 && scrapy crawl somespider -s JOBDIR=crawls/somespider-1`